# Python - convert mysql timestamps type to matplotlib and graph

Tags: python, mysql, matplotlib

After doing a bit of research I am finding it difficult to find out how to use mysql timestamps in matplotlib.

Mysql fields to plot

X-axis:

Field: entered

Type: timestamp

Null: NO

Default: CURRENT TIMESTAMP

Sample: 2017-05-08 18:25:10

Y-axis:

Field: value

Type: float(12,6)

Null: NO

Sample: 123.332

What date format is matplotlib looking for? How do I convert to this format? I found out how to convert from unix timestamp to a format that is acceptable with matplotlib, is unix timestamp better than the timestamp field type I am using? Should I convert my whole table to unix timestamps instead?

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use datetime module,although i use now() function to extract datetime from mysql,but i consider the format is the same。

for instance

python>import datetime as dt

i put the datetime data into a list named datelist,and now you can use  datetime.strptime function to convert the date format to what you want

python>dates = [dt.datetime.strptime(d,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for d in datelist

At last,you can put the list named dates into plot X-axis

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks Maru, really appreciate it!